# How can I add start at a cetrain height property to my JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

My page contains a counter and I want to add a method that makes the counter start when a certain height has been reached. I've calculated that I want the counter to start at the height of 324px, but since I have very little experience with JavaScript I'm not sure what am i looking for. Can someone help me?

Here's my current code:

```
const counters = document.querySelectorAll('.counter');
const speed = 2000;

counters.forEach(counter => {
  const updateCount = () => {
    const target = +counter.getAttribute('data-target');
    const count = +counter.innerText;

    const inc = target / speed;

    if (count < target) {
      counter.innerText = Math.ceil(count + inc);
      requestAnimationFrame(updateCount, 1);
    } else {
      count.innerText = target;
    }
  }

  updateCount();
});
```

```html
  <div class="container-b">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="counters">
          <div class="card-image" id="purple-b">
            <i class="fas fa-users"></i>
            <div class="counter" data-target="231">0</div>
            <p class="card-b-text">Happy Users</p>
          </div>
          <div class="card-image" id="green-b">
            <i class="fas fa-code"></i>
            <div class="counter" data-target="385">0</div>
            <p class="card-b-text">Issues Solved</p>
          </div>
          <div class="card-image" id="red-b">
            <i class="fas fa-cog"></i>
            <div class="counter" data-target="159">0</div>
            <p class="card-b-text">Good Reviews</p>
          </div>
          <div class="card-image" id="orange-b">
            <i class="fas fa-comments"></i>
            <div class="counter" data-target="127">0</div>
            <p class="card-b-text">Case Studies</p>
          </div>
          <div class="card-image" id="blue-b">
            <i class="fas fa-rocket"></i>
            <div class="counter" data-target="211">0</div>
            <p class="card-b-text">Orders Received</p>
            <p></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I think you can achieve this with `window.scrollY`, for example. If `window.scrollY` === your desire height, then you can start running the `function` or the `counters` of yours

Comment: I'm confused, can you add some html and make it closer to the idea of having a [Minimal, Reproducible Example ?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @MisterJojo I don't find it necessary since I only need the code to start the counter. I don't see how my HTML can help you since I've already calculated the height where I want the counter to start. Can you tell me what part are you finding confusing?

Comment: Well, I will try to be clearer, I think that your approach is bad and that it will never be able to succeed. And that I preferred that your problem be posed entirely to propose another mechanism

Comment: @MisterJojo Here's the HTML code https://codeshare.io/JbWO0q, do you need CSS?

Comment: Please read [ask], where it says, “If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/) then do so - **but also copy the code into the question itself.**”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is what you're looking for or not. If it's wrong you can describe it more, because I do not quite understand it.

Let's say I have a page with 3000px
CSS:

```
.counter{
  height: 3000px;
}
```

And I want whenever I scroll pass the 324px, it'll do something for you

```
const counters = document.querySelectorAll('.counter');

window.onscroll=function(){
   if(scrollY >= 324){
        console.log("Do your start count things or something in here")
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this one worked after I took some time to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

I will do that this way :

use the same `requestAnimationFrame()` for both elements, and stop it when there is none to update

```js
const
  speed = 2000
, counters = [...document.querySelectorAll('.counter')]
             .map(el=>(
               { el
               , target : +el.dataset.target
               , inc    : (el.dataset.target / speed)
               , count  : parseInt(el.textContent)
               }))
  ;
requestAnimationFrame(updateCount)

function updateCount()
  {
  let elmsRun = counters.length 
  counters.forEach(({ el, target, inc, count}, i) =>
    {
    el.textContent = counters[i].count 
                   = (count < target) ? Math.ceil(count+inc) : target
    if (counters[i].count === target) --elmsRun
    })
  if (elmsRun) requestAnimationFrame(updateCount)
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, I used a different code to get the result and I can't comment on your code since its too advanced for me to understand. Thanks for the attempt thought, greatly appreciated.